# Filename having pound sign within zip inserted as blank in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, zip

I have a zip file (A.zip) having multiple files in it. When I am trying to insert the filenames in my database field, it is getting inserted as blank in one of the fields.

Here is the code I am using:-

```
    $filename = "A.zip";
    $zip = zip_open($filename); 
    if ($zip) {
        while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
            $zip_file_name = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
            $zip_file_name = preg_replace("/([!?:%,\[\]@{+;}=*<>~#\"^&*|()\\/])/", " ",$zip_file_name);
            // Every single time, the file name is read, it is inserted in the database

    }
    zip_close($zip);
}
```

filenames in zip file:-
1) 178_!£$%^&&@{~~.xslx
2) 128_!£$%^@{~.xslx

I am replacing all the required special characters with the space (" "), but need to keep dollar ($) and pound (£) in the filename (when inserted).

Now, what is happening, all the required characters are correctly getting replaced with spaces and $ is also correctly placed, but when it comes to pound sign (£), it is getting replaced with a black diamond question mark (when I did console log) and a blank filename is getting inserted in the database.

When single file is inserted in the database, it is getting correctly inserted with the $ and pound(£) sign.

field name in the database is varchar(255) with utf8_general_ci as collation.

Also, the meta tag is set as charset UTF-8: -

I have tried looking out for solutions over the internet, but couldn't able to find the one related with zip file.

Just to note: All filenames with simple english characters and numbers are correctly getting inserted into the database.

Also, when I remove the pound sign (£), filename is correctly inserted..

Please..Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What character encoding is your filename in?

Comment: encoding being used is utf8

Comment: Are you sure the filename is UTF-8? What if it's Windows-1252 or something else?

Comment: What's the content of $zip_file_name after the preg_replace function? Also I don't see any code for inserting the fileName into the dB. Please provide more code.